# How connect to Hortonworks sandbox Hbase using Java Client API

Tags: java, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

I have setup fresh Hortonworks sandbox .I'm trying to connect Hbase using Java Client API.This is the code i tried so far.But did not success.I did not change any configuration on Wortonworks sandbox.Do i need to do any configuration part in Hbase ?

```
        Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
        configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "127.0.0.1");
        configuration.set("hbase.master", "127.0.0.1:600000");

        HBaseAdmin hBaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(configuration);
```

Comment: The default `hbase.master.port` port is 60000 and you seem to be using 600000. Can you check if the port matches?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. Here's how I solved it, More details [here](https://cindyxiaoxiaoli.wordpress.com/2015/04/27/remote-connect-to-hbase-on-hortonworks-sandbox-with-java/)

I did this through editing VirtualBox’s Network settings. So there’s no need to modify any configuration files inside the Hortonworks sandbox VM such as the `/etc/hosts` file or the `zoo.cfg` file.

In VirtualBox, for the Hortonworks Sandbox VM:

1. Stop the VM if it’s running
2. Go to Settings -> Network, disable all current network adapters.
3. Create a new Adapter, select `Host-only Adapter`, use the default settings and apply it.
4. Start VM, ssh into it with root@192.168.56.101 (192.168.56.101 is the IP of the host-only adapter of the VM. I found it when I had two adapters enabled: NAT and host-only, ssh into the VM and run `ifconfig`. It seems to be the same for the same version of VM), start hbase through command line.
5. In the machine’s hosts, add

`192.168.56.101 hortonworks.hbase.vm
192.168.56.101 sandbox.hortonworks.com`

Java Code I use

```
Configuration configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "hortonworks.hbase.vm");
configuration.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
```