# How are clients for Hortonworks Sandbox properly configured?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, client, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform

Related: [How connect to Hortonworks sandbox Hbase using Java Client API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598859/how-connect-to-hortonworks-sandbox-hbase-using-java-client-api)

I currently make a proof of concept using the Hortonworks Sandbox in a VM. However, I fail at properly configuring the client (outside the VM, but on the same computer). I looked for documentation as to how a client needs to be configured, but didn't find one.

I need client configuration for accessing HBase and MapReduce, but most appreciated would be a documentation that lists configuration for clients to all parts of the sandbox.

Comment: Its a pain! I went through the same thing, little documentation, half baked samples on the Internet. Would it be helpful if I paste java client code that I am able to connect with out of the box for the hortonworks sandbox?

Comment: @DuncanKrebs Yes, please

Answer (score 2):

It is actually even more stupid than I would have expected. It seems that not all necessary ports are forwarded by default, it is necessary to add them all in the VM configuration.

[image]